# The coefficient of $x^{18}$ in the product $(1-x^2)(1-x^3)^9$ is

Tags: binomial-theorem

The coefficient of $x^{18}$ in the product $(1-x^2)(1-x^3)^9$ is

Now obviously for the power to be 18, the expansion of $(1-x^3)^9$ must have a term with the power 16, however if we do that we get $3r=16$ which is obviously not a natural number

however, from this my book has concluded that the coefficient is the coefficient of the term with the power 18 in $(1-x^3)^9$, namely the 6th term, which gives a coefficient of 84.

I'm not sure I understand why this is the correct coefficient

Comment: Bro u JEE aspirant? Your posts throughout StackExchange seem to indicate that

Comment: sort of, I want to study maths, but there aren't many great math colleges in India

Comment: **Hint**: $(1-x^2)=(1-x)(1+x)$.

Comment: @mathandphysicsforever ah I see

Comment: $(1-x^3)^9 = 1 - 9 x^3 + 36x^6 - 84x^9 + 126x^{12} - 126 x^{15} + \color{red}{84 x^{18}} - 36 x^{21} + 9 x^{24} - x^{27}$ and multiplying the red term by the $1$ in $(1-x^2)$ gives you $x^{18}$ in the final answer. You seem to have a pattern of ignoring the first terms of the smaller multiplicand, seen in both this and your previous (now deleted) post which I commented on.

Comment: @insipidintegrator, got it, sorry, and thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

firstly, expend the right side $$(1-x^3)^9$$ to be
$$\sum_{k=0}^{6} C_9^k1^{9-k}(-x^3)^k$$
thus
$$(1-x^2)(1-x^3)^9 = (1-x^2) * \sum_{k=0}^{6} C_9^k1^{9-k}(-x^3)^k$$
as you can see there are only 2 possibility that term $x^n$ can be $x^{18}$
which would be
$$1 * [C_9^k1^{9-k}(-x^3)^k] = c_1 * x^{18}$$
$$-x^{2} * [C_9^k1^{9-k}(-x^3)^k] = c_2 * x^{18}$$
where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are coefficients

neglecting coefficients, to get power 18, it must satisfies that
$$x^{3k} = x^{18}$$ or
$$x^{2}*x^{3k} = x^{18}$$
the solution is
$$ k = 6 $$ or
$$ k = \frac{16}{3} $$
since k must be integer so $k = 6$
thus you can solve $c_1$ letting k=6
$$C_9^61^{9-6}(-x^3)^6 = c_1 * x^{18}$$
which is
$$84*x^{18} = c_1 x^{18}$$
so $c_1 = 84$ and $c_2$ is impossible

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$
(1-x^2)(1-x^3)^9 = (1-x^3)^9-x^2(1-x^3)^9.
$$
The first summand contains the term $(x^3)^6 = x^{18}$. The second does not, as you observe that $(1-x^3)^9$ does not contain $x^{16}$.

Since
$$
(1-x^3)^9 = \sum_{k=0}^9 \binom{9}{k} (-x^3)^k = \sum_{k=0}^9 \binom{9}{k} (-1)^k x^{3k},
$$
the coefficient of $x^{18}$ is
$$
\binom{9}{6} (-1)^6 = 84.
$$

Comment: thanks, when expanded , won't the power no longer be 18 though?

Comment: @mathandphysicsforever Why not? It is a sum of polynomials, where one contains $x^{18}$ and the other does not.

Comment: yeah, got it. Thanks!